# Why did sendRawTransaction lose some transactions although it returned those transactions' hash values?

Tags: web3js

In a short time within 1 min, 5 transactions were submitted using `sendRawTransaction` of `web3` and the 5 hash values of these txs had been got. But, only 2 transactions could be found in the ethereum private blockchain at last. Why did the ethereum network lose 3 transactions?

Comment: Did you increment the transaction nonce for each transaction?

Comment: For the community to help effectively, please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve